# Can we assume the 'Savages' go unpunished?

Tags: lord-of-the-flies, william-golding

In the end of *The Lord of the Flies*, the boys' rescuer, the Naval Officer, does not comprehend what is really happening, terming it "all fun and games".

Can we assume that the savages, especially Jack and Roger, go totally unpunished?

Ralph is there to speak against them, but he is practically the only one (littleuns don't really count) and he participated in the killing of Simon. This means that telling the Adults is incriminating himself as well.

So will the 'savages' grow up secretly knowing that savagery goes unpunished?

Comment: I would say yes, but I don't have any evidence

Comment: @MatrimCauthon I was worried about that, it is risky to ask a question about events after a book. If this is off topic i will close it. I was hoping that Golding might have said something on the issue though...

Comment: I am not sure if it is off topic. I am going to go start a meta post about it.

Comment: Here it [is](http://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/can-we-assume-the-savages-go-unpunished?noredirect=1#comment2520_1691)

Comment: Just because we don't know the answer, that certainly doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's implied that some sort of conflict or war is occurring while the boys are on the island, which prevents them from being found earlier. So the answer would depend on the condition of the society which the boys are returning to. It's possible Simon had some family who would want an explanation for his disappearance.

Comment: Is it implausible that when a bunch of kids get stranded on an island, some of them will die? It's more likely people will try to protect the kids from having to remember that "harrowing" time.

Comment: Only a few of the people survived the crash, if the boys didn't speak about Simon, Piggy and the boy with the mullberry birthmark there would be no reason for the adults to think that those boys had survived the crash.